# $(a^2) \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$ - we are looking for $a$ - fast way

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We have the equation: $(a^2)  \equiv 1  \pmod{k}$

We know $k$. It is a quick way to find $a$? (of course other than $1$)

Comment: $a=k+1$ works...

Comment: Sorry: And $a$ must be less than $k$.

Comment: $a=k-1$? Btw, this is the only solution besides $a=1$ if $k$ is prime.

Comment: If there are solutions other than $1$ and $-1$, they are closely connected to the prime power factorization of $k$, so can be difficult to compute efficiently when $k$ is a product of two very large primes.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no known fast way to do this. At least assuming $a=k-1$ is also not acceptable.

Suppose you have a polynomial time algorithm to find a nontrivial square root of 1 modulo any natural number $k$. Call this square root $a$. Then you would have $(a+1)(a-1)=km$. Then you could quickly find the greatest common divisor of $(a+1)$ and $k$, and likewise that of $(a-1)$ and $k$. These are nontrivial factors of $k$ as, by assumption, $a$ is not either 1 or -1 mod $k$.

So, we have used our polynomial time modular square root of unity algorithm to get a polynomial time factoring algorithm. There are no known polynomial time factoring algorithms. Therefore, there is no polynomial time modular square root of unity algorithm.

In fact, no known algorithm can have less complexity than a known general purpose factoring algorithm. The best general purpose factoring algorithm is significantly beyond polynomial time, and in practice fairly time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$. $k$ is known. We want to find $a$.

Recall that $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$ means $k \mid (a^2 - 1)$. Using the fact that $a \mid b \rightarrow b = ac$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have the following:

$a^2 - 1 = kc$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$

$a^2 = kc + 1$

Hence $a = \sqrt{kc + 1}$, so there seems to be a number of possible values for $a$. I will admit that I'm not entirely familiar with modular arithmetic, so this may not be correct, but the reasoning at least seems sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have given-$a^2\equiv1\pmod k$

$\implies(a+1)(a-1)=k\times p$[For some integer p]

$\implies k=\frac{(a+1)(a-1)}{k}$.

So, either $(a+1)$ or $(a-1)$ must be divisible by $k$.So, you have to find a suitable '$a$' from here such that $(a+1)$ or $(a-1)$ is divisible $k$.